# How do you configure Firebase in Unity?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity and Firebase.  It is failing to configure.  I have thoroughly read all documentation several times.  I have reviewed all their sample projects.  I have tried everything I can think of!  I have the following code:

```
private void Start()
{
    FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>  //Also tried ContinueWithMainThread
    {
        var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
        if (dependencyStatus == DependencyStatus.Available)
        {
            //I tried waiting 5 seconds here
            Debug.Log("Initializing Firebase");
            //Get error when I call the following line (and no error if I don't)
            var firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
            Debug.Log("Firebase Initialized");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {dependencyStatus}");
        }
    });
}
```

My understanding is that Firebase is not safe to use until I receive the `DependencyStatus` of `Available`.  So that is what I am doing.  I thoroughly logged everything, and Firebase is not configured, even though I am getting an `Available` dependency status.  I get the following error when I try to initialize my FirebaseApp (or call any other Firebase function):

> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization.

I am using Firebase version 6.15.2.  I am on iOS.  I have no problems running on Android.  I have tried removing all packages except for `Firebase App (Core)`, but still get the same error.  (The logs have the packages included.)

Here are some detailed logs:

```
Initializing Firebase
Carbon.Firebase.FirebaseManager:<Start>b__27_0(Task`1)
System.Threading.ContextCallback:Invoke(Object)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext:RunInternal(ExecutionContext, ContextCallback, Object, Boolean)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MoveNextRunner:Run()
System.Action:Invoke()
System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation:RunOrScheduleAction(Action, Boolean, Task&)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task:FinishContinuations()
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1:TrySetResult(TResult)
System.Threading.Tasks.DelayPromise:Complete()
System.Threading.TimerCallback:Invoke(Object)
System.Threading.WaitCallback:Invoke(Object)
System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue:Dispatch()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

2020-08-23 20:59:12.807516-0400 v1[1160:269382] 6.24.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization.
2020-08-23 20:59:12.876636-0400 v1[1160:269421] 6.24.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
2020-08-23 20:59:12.887162-0400 v1[1160:269243] [Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 4.1.0
2020-08-23 20:59:12.911808-0400 v1[1160:269417] 6.24.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60500000 started
2020-08-23 20:59:12.912317-0400 v1[1160:269417] 6.24.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
2020-08-23 20:59:13.045633-0400 v1[1160:269489] Remote Config API Initializing
2020-08-23 20:59:13.055122-0400 v1[1160:269243] FCM: registration token received, but no listener set yet - cached the token.
Remote Config API Initializing
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

FCM: registration token received, but no listener set yet - cached the token.
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

2020-08-23 20:59:13.127161-0400 v1[1160:269489] Remote Config API Initialized
Remote Config API Initialized
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Firebase initialized
Carbon.Firebase.FirebaseManager:<Start>b__27_0(Task`1)
System.Threading.ContextCallback:Invoke(Object)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext:RunInternal(ExecutionContext, ContextCallback, Object, Boolean)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MoveNextRunner:Run()
System.Action:Invoke()
System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation:RunOrScheduleAction(Action, Boolean, Task&)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task:FinishContinuations()
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1:TrySetResult(TResult)
System.Threading.Tasks.DelayPromise:Complete()
System.Threading.TimerCallback:Invoke(Object)
System.Threading.WaitCallback:Invoke(Object)
System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue:Dispatch()
```

And to be excessive, here are the same logs, but with Debug Info turned on:

```
2020-08-23 21:28:52.021254-0400 v1[1175:273744] UnityIAP: Requesting 2 products
2020-08-23 21:28:52.055821-0400 v1[1175:273744] DEBUG: Disabling all app initializers
2020-08-23 21:28:52.056433-0400 v1[1175:273744] DEBUG: Disable analytics
2020-08-23 21:28:52.056556-0400 v1[1175:273744] DEBUG: Disable functions
2020-08-23 21:28:52.056639-0400 v1[1175:273744] DEBUG: Disable messaging
2020-08-23 21:28:52.056728-0400 v1[1175:273744] DEBUG: Disable remote_config
Enable module 'analytics' for 'Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics, Firebase.Analytics'
Firebase.FirebaseApp:InitializeAppUtilCallbacks()
Firebase.FirebaseApp:CheckDependenciesAsync()
Firebase.FirebaseApp:CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync()
Carbon.Firebase.FirebaseManager:Start()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

2020-08-23 21:28:52.057256-0400 v1[1175:273744] DEBUG: analytics app initializer Enabling
2020-08-23 21:28:52.057441-0400 v1[1175:273744] DEBUG: App initializer auth not found, failed to enable.
2020-08-23 21:28:52.057647-0400 v1[1175:273744] DEBUG: App initializer crashlytics not found, failed to enable.
2020-08-23 21:28:52.060160-0400 v1[1175:273744] DEBUG: App initializer database not found, failed to enable.
2020-08-23 21:28:52.060332-0400 v1[1175:273744] DEBUG: App initializer dynamic_links not found, failed to enable.
Enable module 'functions' for 'Firebase.Functions.FirebaseFunctions, Firebase.Functions'
Firebase.FirebaseApp:InitializeAppUtilCallbacks()
Firebase.FirebaseApp:CheckDependenciesAsync()
Firebase.FirebaseApp:CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync()
Carbon.Firebase.FirebaseManager:Start()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

2020-08-23 21:28:52.060646-0400 v1[1175:273744] DEBUG: functions app initializer Enabling
2020-08-23 21:28:52.060833-0400 v1[1175:273744] DEBUG: App initializer instance_id not found, failed to enable.
2020-08-23 21:28:52.060994-0400 v1[1175:273744] DEBUG: App initializer invites not found, failed to enable.
Enable module 'messaging' for 'Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging, Firebase.Messaging'
Firebase.FirebaseApp:InitializeAppUtilCallbacks()
Firebase.FirebaseApp:CheckDependenciesAsync()
Firebase.FirebaseApp:CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync()
Carbon.Firebase.FirebaseManager:Start()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

2020-08-23 21:28:52.061372-0400 v1[1175:273744] DEBUG: messaging app initializer Enabling
2020-08-23 21:28:52.061569-0400 v1[1175:273744] DEBUG: App initializer performance not found, failed to enable.
Enable module 'remote_config' for 'Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig, Firebase.RemoteConfig'
Firebase.FirebaseApp:InitializeAppUtilCallbacks()
Firebase.FirebaseApp:CheckDependenciesAsync()
Firebase.FirebaseApp:CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync()
Carbon.Firebase.FirebaseManager:Start()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

2020-08-23 21:28:52.061829-0400 v1[1175:273744] DEBUG: remote_config app initializer Enabling
2020-08-23 21:28:52.062019-0400 v1[1175:273744] DEBUG: App initializer storage not found, failed to enable.
2020-08-23 21:28:52.062175-0400 v1[1175:273744] DEBUG: App initializer test_lab not found, failed to enable.
Initializing Firebase
Carbon.Firebase.FirebaseManager:InitializeFirebase(DependencyStatus)
System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task:Execute()
System.Threading.ContextCallback:Invoke(Object)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext:RunInternal(ExecutionContext, ContextCallback, Object, Boolean)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task:ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task&)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task:ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue:Dispatch()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Disabling all app initializers
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Disable analytics
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Disable functions
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Disable messaging
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Disable remote_config
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

analytics app initializer Enabling
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

App initializer auth not found, failed to enable.
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

App initializer crashlytics not found, failed to enable.
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

App initializer database not found, failed to enable.
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

App initializer dynamic_links not found, failed to enable.
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

functions app initializer Enabling
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

App initializer instance_id not found, failed to enable.
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

App initializer invites not found, failed to enable.
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

messaging app initializer Enabling
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

App initializer performance not found, failed to enable.
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

remote_config app initializer Enabling
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

App initializer storage not found, failed to enable.
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

App initializer test_lab not found, failed to enable.
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

2020-08-23 21:28:52.135579-0400 v1[1175:273986] DEBUG: Creating Firebase App __FIRAPP_DEFAULT for Firebase C++ 6.15.1
2020-08-23 21:28:52.153491-0400 v1[1175:273919] 6.24.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization.
Creating Firebase App __FIRAPP_DEFAULT for Firebase C++ 6.15.1
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

2020-08-23 21:28:52.584552-0400 v1[1175:273744] UnityIAP: Requesting product data...
2020-08-23 21:28:52.627075-0400 v1[1175:273744] [Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 4.1.0
2020-08-23 21:28:52.677262-0400 v1[1175:273986] DEBUG: Added app name=__FIRAPP_DEFAULT: options, api_key=AIzaSyDfYwUh8pet1DBg-h_Z3aBisGM7-O0pa00, app_id=1:357282509732:ios:0a7799bd3c86c224558731, database_url=https://carbon-weight-loss-v1.firebaseio.com, messaging_sender_id=357282509732, storage_bucket=carbon-weight-loss-v1.appspot.com, project_id=carbon-weight-loss-v1 (0x11a2ca90)
2020-08-23 21:28:52.710093-0400 v1[1175:273986] Remote Config API Initializing
2020-08-23 21:28:52.745216-0400 v1[1175:273986] Remote Config API Initialized
Added app name=__FIRAPP_DEFAULT: options, api_key=AIzaSyDfYwUh8pet1DBg-h_Z3aBisGM7-O0pa00, app_id=1:357282509732:ios:0a7799bd3c86c224558731, database_url=https://carbon-weight-loss-v1.firebaseio.com, messaging_sender_id=357282509732, storage_bucket=carbon-weight-loss-v1.appspot.com, project_id=carbon-weight-loss-v1 (0x11a2ca90)
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Remote Config API Initializing
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Remote Config API Initialized
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

2020-08-23 21:28:52.923641-0400 v1[1175:273744] FCM: registration token received, but no listener set yet - cached the token.
FCM: registration token received, but no listener set yet - cached the token. 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Registering Crashlytics exception handlers
Firebase.Crashlytics.ExceptionHandler:Register()
Firebase.Crashlytics.Crashlytics:Initialize()
System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo)
Firebase.FirebaseApp:InitializeCrashlyticsIfPresent()
System.Func`1:Invoke()
Firebase.<Run>c__AnonStorey0`1:<>m__0()
System.Action:Invoke()
Firebase.ExceptionAggregator:Wrap(Action)
Firebase.Dispatcher:PollJobs()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Firebase initialized
System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task:Execute()
System.Threading.ContextCallback:Invoke(Object)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext:RunInternal(ExecutionContext, ContextCallback, Object, Boolean)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task:ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task&)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task:ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue:Dispatch()
```

I tried the sample apps for Analytics and Crashlytics (separately).  I get the same error on both of them.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you configure your app settings on the firebase console?

Comment: @Lotan yes, and updated my plist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the error message you're seeing is spurious. See [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/498#issuecomment-550553548) for example.

Unless you're seeing any broken functionality, everything looks fine (farther down in your logs there's a `Firebase initialized` and messages about FCM tokens being properly received).

Sometimes you do get issues using `ContinueWith` rather than `ContinueWithOnMainThread` (see this related [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with.html) or [video](https://youtu.be/5GzFDXvZxKM)) which could obfuscate some logging or cause instability. From what I can see, you aren't running into that issue, but it's worth switching that around if `ContinueWith` wasn't a conscious decision.

Comment: Thanks Patrick.  I'll read into that GitHub issue. The `Firebase initialized` is my own log, and does not mean it was initialized.  I tried both `ContinueWith` and `ContinueWithOnMainThread`, but without a difference.

Comment: I do not think the error is Spurious, because my Crashlytics fails to connect.

Comment: In that case, make sure you've configured Crashlytics, and try downloading your GoogleServices-Info.plist again just in case (sometimes this solves stuff). But it looks like you're doing everything right, so you could file an issue here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues

Comment: Configured Crashlytics...is there anything to configure?  I am just including the package and pressing Enable Crashlytics on the console.  (Then forcing a crash on device.)

Comment: It looked like I am having this issue (with the sample project too), of which it seems you are already aware.  I am not migrating from Fabric, like the other user.  Is there anything I can do to help you help me with this bug? :)  https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/740

Comment: I went and linked this issue over to GitHub as well.

Comment: I just read your article medium.com/firebase-developers/…: "What has crashed shall never crash". Feel obligated to point out your pun to others. :-) Great article though.